# How to fill product attribute based on two others

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, product-attribute

I have to fill programmatically attribute from two others. For example have attribute `price_shippment` and have to fill it from `shippment`+`price`.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "autofill" this attribute when product is saved.

Add a extension with this code:

> app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <fill_attribute>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>fillAttribute</method>
                    </fill_attribute>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function fillAttribute($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $price = $product->getPrice();

        $product->setData('cena_z_przesylka_en', $price + $product->getKosztPrzesylkiEn());
        $product->setData('cena_z_przesylka_de', $price + $product->getKosztPrzesylkiDe());
        $product->setData('cena_z_przesylka_fr', $price + $product->getKosztPrzesylkiFr());
        $product->setData('cena_z_przesylka_it', $price + $product->getKosztPrzesylkiIt());
        $product->setData('cena_z_przesylka_es', $price + $product->getKosztPrzesylkiEs());
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Massupdate

Run this code from Magentos root directory:

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$action = new MyProductAction;

$action->setPrices();

class MyProductAction
{
    public function setPrices()
    {
        $attributes = array(
            'price',
            'koszt_przesylki_en',
            'koszt_przesylki_de',
            'koszt_przesylki_fr',
            'koszt_przesylki_it',
            'koszt_przesylki_es',
        );

        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes, 'inner');

        Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
            $products->getSelect(),
            array(array($this, 'setPricesCallback'))
        );
    }

    public function setPricesCallback($args)
    {
        var_dump($args);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
            array($args['row']['entity_id']),
            array(
                'cena_z_przesylka_en' => $args['row']['price'] + $args['row']['koszt_przesylki_en'],
                'cena_z_przesylka_de' => $args['row']['price'] + $args['row']['koszt_przesylki_de'],
                'cena_z_przesylka_fr' => $args['row']['price'] + $args['row']['koszt_przesylki_fr'],
                'cena_z_przesylka_it' => $args['row']['price'] + $args['row']['koszt_przesylki_it'],
                'cena_z_przesylka_es' => $args['row']['price'] + $args['row']['koszt_przesylki_es']
            ),
            null
        );
    }
}
```

**Note:** if it doesn't work, do the following first:

1. open product grid
2. select all
3. update attributes
4. submit
5. check "change" checkboxes for "price_shippment" attributes but leave input field empty
6. save

Comment: sv3n,Nothing happened. Attribute are empty

Comment: Have you also the other files that are requiered for an extension? This code is successfully tested.

Comment: Added code for `My_Module.xml` ... add these files and flush cache. Should work ;)

Comment: still empty. Bellow listen my attributes ti fill it:
cena_z_przesylka_en = koszt_przesylki_en + price
cena_z_przesylka_de = koszt_przesylki_de + price
cena_z_przesylka_fr = koszt_przesylki_fr + price
cena_z_przesylka_it = koszt_przesylki_it + price
cena_z_przesylka_es = koszt_przesylki_es + price

Comment: Updated and tested ;) Please add `Mage::log('test', null, 'observer.log', true)` to `fillAttribute` and check if `observer.log` is generated in `var/log` after product save.

Comment: Where I have to add   Mage::log('test', null, 'observer.log', true) ?

Comment: Inside `fillAttribute($observer) { ... }`

Comment: attribute empty, and don't see observer.log

Comment: I put code like this :
{
    public function fillAttribute ($observer) { Mage::log('test', null, 'observer.log', true) }
    {

Comment: Well ... if there is no logfile then the module seems not to be loaded! Please check if all files are at their correct place.

Comment: app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Obserwer.php
app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml

Comment: Typo in `app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Obserwer.php`? "w" vs. "v" ... You can also enable logging from Admin-System-Config and check `system.log` and `exception.log`.

Comment: I'm so stupid ! Works like a charms :) How can I thank you?

Comment: Hi, how can I do it with 25000 products? I'm try to re save products but nothing happened

Comment: Updated answer ... it may take some time to run, maybe you have to split the collection in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `php` file with below code in you magento setup root folder and execute in browser.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*");
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setPriceShippment($product->getPrice() + $product->getShippment());
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Mage::app('default');` be `Mage::app();` instead?

Comment: I think you are right, if there is no `default` store it will generate error